# Navigating Differences in Scale: A multivariate approach with standardization or separate component analysis?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, interaction, multivariate-analysis, standardization

I am conducting a research study on sex differences in the physical limitations of patients with **ankylosing spondylitis** (AS), using the **Bath Ankylosing Spondylitis Metrology Index** (BASMI). The [BASMI](https://www.mdapp.co/basmi-score-bath-ankylosing-spondylitis-metrology-index-calculator-616/) is a composite score that consists of five components, including cervical rotation (measured in degrees), tragus-to-wall distance, intermalleolar distance, modified Schober's test, and lumbar side flexion. Each component is scored on a different scale, with most of them being distances measured in centimeters, but each having a distinct range. For example, intermalleolar distance can be up to 120 cm, whereas tragus-to-wall distance is usually between 5-15 cm.

To account for the differences in scale, I am considering two approaches for my analysis: (1) standardizing each component by converting them to z-scores and performing a multivariate linear mixed model analysis, and (2) performing separate analyses for each component (i.e, a univariate analysis). My main research question is focused on analyzing sex differences in the physical limitations of the patients, and how these differences vary across the individual BASMI components over time after treatment.

However, I am concerned about how to interpret the regression coefficients if I choose to standardize the components, as well as how to explain the implications of this approach in my research report or paper. On the other hand, performing separate analyses for each component may result in a loss of statistical power due to smaller sample sizes for each component, and may not account for the correlations between the components.

I would appreciate any advice or guidance on the advantages and disadvantages of these approaches, and how to choose the most appropriate approach for my specific research question and data.